# I am doing integration in R and defined a function N as follows:

Tags: r

```
r12=10; r21=10; r13=10; r31=10; r14=10; r41=10; r15=10; r51=10; r23=10; r32=10;
r24=10; r42=10; r25=10; r52=10; r34=10; r43=10; r35=10; r53=10; r45=10; r54=10;
w121=6; w211=4; w131=7; w311=4; w141=3; w411=6; w151=7; w511=4; w231=7; w321=4;
w241=5; w421=5; w251=6; w521=3; w341=3; w431=6; w351=5; w531=3; w451=6; w541=4;
w122=3; w212=5; w132=2; w312=4; w142=7; w412=3; w152=3; w512=5; w232=3; w322=5;
w242=5; w422=4; w252=4; w522=6; w342=6; w432=3; w352=4; w532=6; w452=3; w542=5;
T12=1; T21=1; T13=1; T31=1; T14=0; T41=1; T15=0; T51=1; T23=0; T32=1;
T24=0; T42=1; T25=0; T52=1; T34=1; T43=1; T35=1; T53=1; T45=1; T54=1;
Eps=0.05;
S1=w121+w212+w131+w312+w141+w412+w151+w512+0.5*(T12+T21+T13+T31+T14+T41+T15+T51);
S2=w211+w122+w231+w232+w241+w422+w251+w522+0.5*(T21+T12+T23+T32+T24+T42+T25+T52);
S3=w311+w132+w321+w232+w341+w432+w351+w532+0.5*(T31+T13+T32+T23+T34+T43+T35+T53);
S4=w411+w142+w421+w242+w431+w342+w451+w542+0.5*(T41+T14+T42+T24+T43+T34+T45+T54);
S5=w511+w152+w521+w252+w531+w352+w541+w452+0.5*(T51+T15+T52+T25+T53+T35+T54+T45);
T=T12+T21+T13+T31+T14+T41+T15+T51+T23+T32+T24+T42+T25+T52+T34+T43+T35+T53+T45+T54;
K=w122+w212+w132+w312+w142+w412+w152+w512+w232+w322+w242+w422+w252+w522+w342+w432+w352+w532+w452+w542;
N=integrate(Vectorize(function(t1){
  integrate(Vectorize(function(t2){
    integrate(Vectorize(function(t3){
      integrate(Vectorize(function(t4){
        integrate(Vectorize(function(V){
          integrate(function(G){
            ((t1**S1)*(t2**S2)*(t3**S3)*(t4**S4)*((1-t1-t2-t3-t4)**S5)*(G**K)*(V**T))/
              (((t1+G*t2+V*(t1*t2)**0.5)**r12)*((t2+G*t1+V*(t2*t1)**0.5)**r21)*
                 ((t1+G*t3+V*(t1*t3)**0.5)**r13)*((t3+G*t1+V*(t3*t1)**0.5)**r31)*
                 ((t1+G*t4+V*(t1*t4)**0.5)**r14)*((t4+G*t1+V*(t4*t1)**0.5)**r41)*
                 ((t1+G*(1-t1-t2-t3-t4)+V*(t1*(1-t1-t2-t3-t4))**0.5)**r15)*(((1-t1-t2-t3-t4)+G*t1+V*((1-t1-t2-t3-t4)*t1)**0.5)**r51)*
                 ((t2+G*t3+V*(t2*t3)**0.5)**r23)*((t3+G*t2+V*(t3*t2)**0.5)**r32)*
                 ((t2+G*t4+V*(t2*t4)**0.5)**r24)*((t4+G*t2+V*(t4*t2)**0.5)**r42)*
                 ((t2+G*(1-t1-t2-t3-t4)+V*(t2*(1-t1-t2-t3-t4))**0.5)**r25)*(((1-t1-t2-t3-t4)+G*t2+V*((1-t1-t2-t3-t4)*t2)**0.5)**r52)*
                 ((t3+G*t4+V*(t3*t4)**0.5)**r34)*((t4+G*t3+V*(t4*t3)**0.5)**r43)*
                 ((t3+G*(1-t1-t2-t3-t4)+V*(t3*(1-t1-t2-t3-t4))**0.5)**r35)*(((1-t1-t2-t3-t4)+G*t3+V*((1-t1-t2-t3-t4)*t3)**0.5)**r53)*
                 ((t4+G*(1-t1-t2-t3-t4)+V*(t4*(1-t1-t2-t3-t4))**0.5)**r45)*(((1-t1-t2-t3-t4)+G*t4+V*((1-t1-t2-t3-t4)*t3)**0.5)**r54))
          }, Eps, 3-Eps)$value 
        }), Eps, 3-Eps)$value 
      }), Eps, 1-t1-t2-t3-Eps)$value 
    }), Eps, 1-t1-t2-Eps)$value 
  }), Eps, 1-t1-Eps)$value 
}), Eps, 1-Eps)
```

and I get this error:

```
Error in integrate(function(G) { : non-finite function value
```

Since the function 'N' has random variables t1, t2, t3, t4, t5 between 0 and 1 with constraint t1+t2+t3+t4+t5=1. and G and V between 0 to Infinity, it should be positive everywhere, though it might be very close to zero. I don't understand why it has non-finite value somewhere.

Could anybody give an advice or help regarding this?

Comment: Wow, NaginaZulfiqar, that is some impressive nested integrating! That's going to be difficult to troubleshoot ... when I inserted a quick counter in the inner-most function to try to find the problem, I crashed my R and had to start over :-(. I suggest you do two things: (1) for readability, define your function formally; then (2) within that function, assign `out <- ((t1**S1)*(...); if (!is.finite(out)) browser(); out`, so that when it occurs, you can see the conditions that led to the error. (Note that `is.finite(NA)` is false, which is IMO a good thing.

Comment: That may not catch it, but perhaps it'll be a decent start ...

Comment: (Otherwise, that's a bit of a daunting question, to be honest! If you can reduce the nesting to just the number of integrations required to trigger the error, that would improve the cost-of-entry for others to try to help you.)

Comment: It's too much information. You must to simplify your question.